# How secure remote debugging Azure Web App is?

Tags: azure, remote-debugging

How secure is remote debugging Azure Web App Service using Visual Studio ( Local Machine )
Is traffic Encrypted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First preference is always to local debugging. If that is not possible, then go for remote debugging.As long as you follow the general recommendations for debugging, it should be secure. You can read more about [Debugger Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-security?view=vs-2019).